# FbxAnimCurve has different behavior between SDK 2016 and 2009 version

Tags: fbx

I upgraded my FBX SDK to 2016, but got a bug.

**Old code is:**

`KFbxCamera * FBXPopulator::GetActiveCamera( KTime & a_Time ) const
{
    KFbxCameraSwitcher* cameraSwitcher = m_Scene->GetGlobalCameraSettings().GetCameraSwitcher();
    if ( cameraSwitcher )
    {
        KFCurve* curve = cameraSwitcher->CameraIndex.GetKFCurve( NULL, m_Scene->GetCurrentTakeName() );
        if ( curve )
        {
            int32_t index = static_cast< int32_t >( curve->Evaluate( a_Time ) - 1 );
            return m_DeclaredCameras[ index ]->GetCamera();
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}`

**Current code is:**

`FbxCamera * FBXPopulator::GetActiveCamera(FbxTime & a_Time) const
{
    FbxCameraSwitcher* cameraSwitcher = m_Scene->GlobalCameraSettings().GetCameraSwitcher();
    if (cameraSwitcher)
    {
            //Is it right here?
        FbxAnimCurve* curve = cameraSwitcher->CameraIndex.GetCurve(m_Scene->GetCurrentAnimationStack()->GetMember());
        if (curve)
        {
            int32_t index = static_cast< int32_t >(curve->Evaluate(a_Time) - 1);
            return m_DeclaredCameras[index]->GetCamera();
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}`

Is it wrong?

I got index == 0 in 2009 version while index == 1 in 2016 version.

Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, new SDK can't read some field correctly.
I just convert fbx files with FBX Converter 2009.
It works.
But I don't know why.